# Get error information if luaL_loadfile fails

Tags: lua

If `luaL_load` function fails, then, according to the documentation (Lua5.1), the *error message* is pushed on the stack and can be retrieved with `lua_tostring(L, -1)`, but if I want to print a customized error message, I don't think I can use  `lua_Debug` (because that is for *active function*). Is there any other way (other than parsing the string) to get the *file*, *line number* and *what error occured* ?

--
Thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error code returned by `luaL_loadfile` tells you what kind of error happened. You're mostly likely only interested in `LUA_ERRSYNTAX`, in which case there is a detailed error message left on the stack. This is the only record of the error. If you need to reformat it, you need to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

During a luaL_load(), there is nothing techinally on the stack that is relavant to the loading of the script. No functions are performed or executed in the script. Its just a compilation step, returning a function that encapsulates the whole file or the error found during compilation.

If you get a function back, you execute this to actually run the script, which sounds like what you are really interested in. In which case you can use a lua_pcall() and provide an error handler. In your handler you would then have your expected stack trace available via lua_Debug.